# Merging Two Lists in Racket R5RS

Tags: list, scheme, append, racket

I'm supposed to create a function called ( merge-list lst1 lst2) that alternately picks elements from one of the two input lists and creates a new list. For example the output of 
 (merge-list ‘(2 4) ‘(b c)) is  '(2 b 4 c). Here's what I have so far, but when I compile I am receiving the "application:not a procedure" error

```
 (define (merge-list lst1 lst2)
```

(cond ((null? lst1) lst2)

```
 ((null? lst2) lst1))

  (append( append(list(car lst1) list(car lst2)))list-shuffle((cdr lst1)(cdr lst2))))
```

Comment: You should get the basics right. In Scheme we don't call a function like this: `list-shuffle(lst1 lst2)`. The correct way  (and _do_ mind the parentheses!) is: `(list-shuffle lst1 lst2)`.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is simpler than you think, we don't even have to use `append` - in fact, you should *avoid* using `append`, whenever possible use `cons` for building an output list: this is because `append` does more work and can potentially lead to `O(n^2)` solutions. Try this instead:

```
(define (merge-list lst1 lst2)
  (cond ((null? lst1) lst2)    ; if the first list is empty, return the second
        ((null? lst2) lst1)    ; if the second list is empty, return the first
        (else (cons (car lst1) ; otherwise `cons` the first element of the first list
                    (merge-list lst2 (cdr lst1)))))) ; and interleave the lists
```

It works as expected for lists of the same length:

```
(merge-list '(2 4) '(b c))
=> '(2 b 4 c)

(merge-list '(2 4 6) '(b c d))
=> '(2 b 4 c 6 d)
```

Comment: Admittedly a more elegant solution, perfectly valid as per the original specification.  I didn't realize that `append` could lead to `O(n^2)` time complexity, any reference on that ?

Comment: @xbug it's basically the same problem with [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter.27s_algorithm): each `append` needs to traverse one list to the end, and as the list grows, this will be more costly. That's why `cons` is so cheap: we just stick elements at the beginning.